# WinAPI - GDI: DrawText() and ExtTextOut() ugly (AA enabled)

Tags: winapi

Im trying to make line numbering for a rich edit control using the method described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.cppbuilder.vcl.components.using/tree/browse_frm/thread/e1c1093aabd7b345/640a45bd65903e29?rnum=1&_done=/group/borland.public.cppbuilder.vcl.components.using/browse_frm/thread/e1c1093aabd7b345/640a45bd65903e29?pli=1&#doc_2a5c8e53253996e1) (not MFC though). While it works fine, the rendering of line numbers is really ugly compared to the rich edit.

I made a small program to reproduce the problem: (sorry that I copy paste but couldnt find a normal file hosting service -.-):

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT WINAPI WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch( msg )
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
            HDC bdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            HBITMAP bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 400, 100);

            int height = -MulDiv(10, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);

            HFONT font = CreateFont(
                height, 0, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
                DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
                ANTIALIASED_QUALITY, FF_DONTCARE, "Consolas");

            HGDIOBJ oldbm = SelectObject(bdc, bitmap);
            HGDIOBJ oldft = SelectObject(bdc, font);

            RECT rc = { 0, 0, 200, 20 };

            FillRect(bdc, &rc, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));

            DrawText(bdc, " 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9", 19, &rc, DT_LEFT|DT_EDITCONTROL);
            BitBlt(hdc, 20, 20, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, bdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            SelectObject(bdc, oldbm);
            SelectObject(bdc, oldft);

            DeleteObject(bitmap);
            DeleteObject(font);
            DeleteDC(bdc);
        }
        return 1;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_KEYUP:
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            break;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    HWND hwnd = 0;

    WNDCLASSEX wc =
    {
        sizeof(WNDCLASSEX),
        CS_CLASSDC,
        (WNDPROC)WndProc,
        0L, 0L,
        hInst,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        "TestClass", NULL
    };

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    int w = GetSystemMetrics(0);
    int h = GetSystemMetrics(1);

    DWORD style = WS_CLIPCHILDREN|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|WS_SYSMENU|WS_BORDER|WS_CAPTION;

    hwnd = CreateWindowA("TestClass", "Winapi1", style,
        (w - 400) / 2, (h - 200) / 2, 400, 200,
        NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);

    if( !hwnd )
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Could not create window!", "Error!", MB_OK);
        goto _end;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(msg));

    while( msg.message != WM_QUIT )
    {
        while( PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE) )
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

_end:
    UnregisterClass("TestClass", wc.hInstance);
    return 0;
}
```

A comparison of the result with typing the text into a rich edit:

*(...can't post image -.- ...)*

While the difference is 'subtle' if I enlarge the image it shows that rich edit uses some kind of coloring.

I tried the following things:

- using ExTextOut
- saving the bitmap to file to see if its ugly too (it is)
- drawing directly into hdc (also ugly plus it flickers but thats not an issue right now)

What am I missing?

Comment: Use CLEARTYPE_QUALITY instead, only setting that makes Consolas look good.

Comment: omg thanks :) I feel so stupid now... : /